# All graphs are written to the same plot

Tags: python, anaconda, heatmap, seaborn, spyder

I am using `Spyder 3.1.2, Python 3.6.0 (Annaconda)`

When I run the code - all of these graphs show up on the same plot?

Data is a data table

```
import seaborn as sns

#==============================================================================
# Co-orelation text matrix and the heatMap
#============================================================================== 

    sns.heatmap(corrmat, vmax=1., square=True).xaxis.tick_top()

#==============================================================================
# Scatter plot using Principal components
#==============================================================================

    sns.lmplot("PC1", "PC2", bar, hue="Class", fit_reg=True)


#==============================================================================
# Profile plot
#==============================================================================

    ax = data[["V2","V3","V4","V5","V6"]].plot()
    ax.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `ax` keywords here.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

#if you want them stacked vertically 
f, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(1, 3)

sns.heatmap(corrmat, vmax=1., square=True, ax=ax1)
ax1.xaxis.tick_top()

sns.lmplot("PC1", "PC2", bar, hue="Class", fit_reg=True, ax=ax2)

data[["V2","V3","V4","V5","V6"]].plot(ax=ax3)
ax3.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))
```

You could also just call `plt.figure()` before each plotting call, which will give you 3 separate plots.